# How do i show that finite abelian group is solvable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group.

How do i show that $G$ is solvable using Fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups?

Comment: All subgroups of Abelian groups are normal. Hints might be to find a normal subgroup of prime order and use induction.

Comment: Any abelian group is solvable (actually nilpotent): indeed, what's the commutator subgroup? What's your definition of solvable group?

Comment: I don't get it. My definition for a solvable group is a group which contains a composition series $\{H_i\}$ such that $H_{i+1}/H_i$ is abelian

Comment: @user156562 This is really an uncommon definition of solvability: usually the definition is “$G$ is solvable if $G^{(n)}=\{1\}$ for some $n$”, where $G^{(0)}=G$ and $G^{(k+1)}$ is the commutator subgroup of $G^{(k)}$. For finite groups, the existence of a composition series with abelian factors is then derived using the fundamental theorem on abelian groups.

Comment: @egreg Are you sure this is not conmon?? My definition is indeed the first definition on here:http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group

Comment: @user156562 The equivalence the author says to hold is valid only for ***finite*** groups. The definition with the derived series doesn't require finiteness.

Comment: @egreg That's nice to know thank you :) By the way, i'm considering only finite groups.

Comment: @user156562 By the way, the author of the article uses “composition series” where actually “normal series” is meant. Only in this case the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: @egreg You said the trivial series $H_0=1,H_1=G$ is a composition series is a series in desire. I don't get this.. $H_1/H_0$ need not be simple.. And i wrote "composition" above in my comment..

Comment: @user156562 Not a ***composition*** series, but a ***normal*** series (that is, each term is normal in the following one).

Comment: @egreg so how do i get a composition series? I want to show that every finite abelian group is solvable..

Comment: @egreg: Dear egreg, What you call a *normal* series, most authors would call a *subnormal* series.  Also, a *composition series* is simply a maximal subnormal series (or, in your terminology, a normal series), i.e. one in which all the successive factors are simple.  (Let me suppose I'm working with finite groups, so there are no problems with imagining such maximal subnormal series.)  So there is not so much difference between your definition and the OP's.  Regards,

Answer (score 6):

Terminology can change from one book to another.

#### From J. S. Rose, *A course in the theory of groups*, Cambridge University Press

> If $G$ is a group, a *series* in $G$ is a sequence of subgroups
>   $$
> \{1\}=H_0\unlhd H_1\unlhd H_2\unlhd\dots\unlhd H_{n-1}\unlhd H_n=G
> $$
>   where $H_{k-1}$ is normal in $H_k$ ($k=1,2,\dots,n$). […] Some authors call this a *normal series*. […] A series is *abelian* if every factor $H_k/H_{k-1}$ is abelian.
>
> A group is called *soluble* (*solvable* by American authors) if it has an abelian series.

#### From S. Lang, *Algebra*, Springer-Verlag

> Let $G$ be a group. A sequence of subgroups
>   $$
> G=G_0\supset G_1\supset G_2\supset \dots\supset G_m
> $$
>   is called a *tower* of subgroups. A tower of subgroups is said to be *normal* if each $G_{i+1}$ is normal in $G_i$ ($i=0,1,\dots,m-1$). It is said to be *abelian* (resp. *cyclic*) if it is normal and each factor group $G_i/G_{i+1}$ is abelian (resp. cyclic).
>
> […]
>
> A group is said to be *solvable* if it has an abelian tower whose last element is the trivial subgroup (i.e. $G_m=\{e\}$ in the above notation).

---

I'll follow the first cited book. If we denote by $G'$ the subgroup of $G$ generated by the commutators $[g,h]=ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$, it's easy to see that $G'$ is normal in $G$ and that $G/G'$ is abelian. Now we can continue and define, by recursion,
$$
G^{(0)}=G,\qquad G^{(k+1)}=(G^{(k)})'
$$
It's also easy to show that a group is solvable if and only there exists $n$ such that $G^{(n)}=\{1\}$. In particular every abelian group is solvable, because $G'=\{1\}$ for an abelian group $G$.

Note: in the [article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group) the author uses *composition series* where *normal series* (or simply *series*) should be used. A *composition series* is a series in which every factor is simple. An abelian group may fail to have composition series, the simplest example is the group of integers, but it is solvable nonetheless. So the equivalence stated at the beginning of the article is false, if *composition series* are used instead of *normal series*.

In the case of finite groups, it is indeed true that a group is solvable if and only if it has an abelian composition series. One direction is trivial.

For the other direction, consider an abelian series
$$
\{1\}=H_0\unlhd H_1\unlhd H_2\unlhd\dots\unlhd H_{n-1}\unlhd H_n=G.
$$
Now we can consider a factor $H_{i}/H_{i-1}$. Call it $K$. Then $K$ is finite abelian, so it has a simple subgroup $K_1$. The group $K/K_1$ is again abelian, so it has a simple subgroup $K_2/K_1$; we can continue until we reach $K$. Thus we get a set of subgroups of $H_i$ containing $H_{i-1}$ that we can insert in the original series; repeat for each $i=1,2,\dots,n$ and finally you get a composition series with abelian factors.